# ClassNotFoundException on shared hosting

Tags: symfony

I am getting this error only in the production server, which is a shared hosting plan.

```
ClassNotFoundException in ContainerBuilderDebugDumpPass.php line 33:
Attempted to load class "Filesystem" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Filesystem".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Twig_Cache_Filesystem" or "Twig_Loader_Filesystem"?
```

I checked the file and it uses the `use` statement:

```
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
```

It's maybe file permissions issue? Any help.

**EDIT**:

I noticed something weird, the Filesystem.php is missing, and when I try to upload it, it disappears automatically. I tried to create and new file and when I pasted the contents of Filesystem.php it vanished again.

Comment: Did you run composer to import all vendors?

Comment: @Veve I upload the vendors from my local machine. I can't run composer on the server because I don't have ssh access, only cPanel.

Comment: Then do you have the file vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem.php ?

Comment: @goto I noticed something weird, the Filesystem.php is missing, and when I try to upload it, it disappears automatically. I tried to create and new file and when I pasted the contents of Filesystem.php it vanished again.

Comment: @giannisf what do you mean paste the content? you upload it to the server?